# Port mirroring on CISCO 2960S

Tags: cisco, cisco-asa

I am trying to do a port mirroring of the traffic for my core switch to a port on my managed switch.

The environment that i have is a stacked switch, with 1 serving as the core switch and 2 serving as the managed switch. This is a layer 2 switch

I have tried to do a port mirror of the entire VLAN, however there seems to be very very little traffic and i am unable to monitor the user traffic.

i have used the following commands to do port mirroring.

monitor session 1 source vlan 1 monitor session 1 destination interface fa0/18

May i know what am i doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for the help

I hope this is the correct place to post this
As this is the closest place i can find in the exchange community.

Comment: vlan 1 is usually special (the default vlan, often untagged);  Is there a reason you are specifying that VLAN instead of a specific port to monitor?  Also, it isn't clear to me whether you have a total of two switches (stacked together presumably), or three (one as core, one stack of two as managed) or that all of the switches are Cat2960S.

Comment: Hi Slart, there are all stacked together. And all the switches are Cat2960S. We are trying to monitor all the user traffic that is passing through the core switch for inspection purposes. I am doing a network health check using an endpoint security device.

Comment: fa0/18 (fast ethernet, plus no stack ID for the switch) tells me you are using an unstacked Catalyst2960SF or 2960 w/o stacking capability. In that case, you won't get data from both switches.  See here for why I think that: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/switches/catalyst-2960-series-switches/models-comparison.html and here for my interpretation of the interface ID: http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_55_se/configuration/guide/scg_2960/swint.html#wp1050439